# keep existing indentation, whitespaces, etc. when parsing and modifying an xml file

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, indentation

Is there some Java library that can help me parse an XML file, change something and then write the output to a new XML file that basically looks exactly as the first one in terms of indentation, whitespaces?

I've tried Jdom but it seems it's XMLOutputter class changes indentation of my original xml.

So basically, if my input xml file looks like this:

```
<root><node>A</node></root>
```

and I want to change A to B, the output should look like:

```
<root><node>B</node></root>
```

and not like

```
<root>
    <node>B</node>
</root>
```

like Jdom outputs it.

This is just an example but my point would be: is there some xml parsing lib that takes into account the formatting of the initial xml file?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is facing this issue, take a look into

[preserve formatting when updating xml file with groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690526/preserve-formatting-when-updating-xml-file-with-groovy)

Just by adding jaxen as a dependency in my pom.xml with the format options as below, preserves output xml file format the same as input (With minor changes).

Format.getRawFormat().setLineSeparator(LineSeparator.NONE)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Format.getRawFormat()` for `XMLOutputter`:

```
XMLOutputter outputter = new XMLOutputter(Format.getRawFormat());
outputter.outputString(document);
```

[Documentation](http://www.jdom.org/docs/apidocs/org/jdom2/output/Format.html#getRawFormat%28%29) for Format.getRawFormat() says:

"Returns a new Format object that performs **no whitespace changes**, uses the UTF-8 encoding,  doesn't expand empty elements, includes the declaration and encoding, and uses the default entity escape strategy."

Comment: Hmm, raw format is not good for me. If you have some comments in the xml file which are each on a new line, raw format will compress them to fit into one line. Also, in my test example, I've had a <project> tag on the next line after last comment. Raw format basically put <project> tag on the same line as the concatenated comments. So not good:)

Comment: Format.getRawFormat().setTextMode(Format.TextMode.PRESERVE) doesn't help neither?

Comment: Nope, already tried any possible combination of those flags:) It seems the initial formatting and indentation of the input xml are forever lost:)